# read specific number of bytes from serial in java

Tags: java, file, byte

I am reading bytes from a SD using arduino to a java application. this is my approach:

```
 if(temp.contains("_i_;")){
                imgByte = new ArrayList<>();
                imgByte.clear();

             for(int i=0; i< min(imgSize , 64) ;i++){
                                    imgByte.add((byte)rx.getInputStream().read());

                                             imgSize--;
             }  
             Files.write(imgFile, toByteArray(imgByte),StandardOpenOption.APPEND );
             System.out.println("Left: "+imgSize);
                   return true; 
             }
```

*i*; is just indicates a 64 packet is coming.

but it is too slow that i can't receive the picture on time. is there another way for doing that so i can read all 64 bytes in only one line? and not iterating with a for loop?
P.S: toByteArray converts byte ArrayList to byte[] so i can write it to file .
I am using jSerialComm library from serial communication

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
Files.copy(rx.getInputStream(), imgFile);
```

Comment: it would work if i had all the bytes ready. bytes are being sent from arduino in packets. and meanwhile other data are comming too. so they can't be stored in a file.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem in the following way:

```
if(temp.contains("_i_;")){
                imgByte = new ArrayList<>();
                imgByte.clear();
                byte[] data = new byte[64];
            // for(int i=0; i< min(imgSize , 64) ;i++){
                                   // imgByte.add((byte)rx.getInputStream().read());
                                   rx.getInputStream().read(data, 0, min(imgSize , 64));
                                             imgSize-=min(imgSize , 64);
           //  }  
             //Files.write(imgFile, toByteArray(imgByte),StandardOpenOption.APPEND );
             Files.write(imgFile, data,StandardOpenOption.APPEND );
             System.out.println("Left: "+imgSize);
                   return true; 
             }
```